# Can we use variable of one .js file to other .js file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have one `aspx` file and i have called 2 `js` file to same `aspx` so now can i use variable of first `js` to other `js` ?

Comment: **Yes, you can!!**. I don't know how your `a.js` and `b.js` is structured? Can you post a.js and b.js code structure.

Comment: It depends on scope of the variable. If it's global you can, but local variables you can't access directly, you must expose it globally.
Try to check if the variable is accessible in global context using "window" object of DOM, like this: alert(window["nameOfVariable"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count variable has to be defined globally and the file where it is defined needs to be loaded first. If a.js has code something like:

```
    var $PAGE = ($PAGE) || {};
    $PAGE.count = 0;
```

and in b.js you can use the object $PAGE.count

Comment: i have updated the answer. the property ,'count' does not exist globally and hence the problem. Best way is to create a global js file and put the global object and properties in there. refer to this js in your bundle/layout/masterpage so it is created and available before it is referenced.

Comment: this is beyond the original question though. I have created a fiddle which has a single file but the idea is same.If you have the click event in a different file, the value will not change. http://jsfiddle.net/man_luck/kb6L0fhv/

Comment: if you define     var $PAGE = ($PAGE) || {};
    $PAGE.count = 0; in ready funtion it will not be global. If it has to be in ready then dont use var just use; $PAGE = ($PAGE) || {};

Comment: have a look at http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html to see the difference between local and global variable declarations